# In lambda calculus, how would I write a function that returns true when its input is the identity function?

Tags: lambda-calculus

In lambda calculus, how would I write a function that returns true when its input is the identity function?

Assume true is some church encoded value of true.

It seems like this should be an easy function to write.  But for every test I think of, a tricky input can outsmart it.  Is it impossible?

Comment: Is that "if the input is the identity function" or "if **and only if** the input is the identity function"? The former is trivial, the latter impossible.

Comment: This sounds like the halting problem to me. I don't know how you could possibly write it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
I := λx.x
0 := λf.λx.x
1 := λf.λx.f x
TRUE := λx.λy.x
FALSE := λx.λy.y
PRED := λn.λf.λx.n (λg.λh.h (g f)) (λu.x) (λu.u)
ISZERO := λn.n (λx.FALSE) TRUE
```

The identity function `λx.x` is Eta equivalent to church numeral 1 `λf.λx.f x`. The Fn below will return `FALSE` for any function that does not evaluate to a church numeral zero (`λf.λx.x`) after being passed through the predicate function.

```
λx.(ISZERO (PRED x)) TRUE FALSE
```

There may exist a function BAD that behaves as such:

```
λx.(ISZERO (PRED x)) TRUE FALSE BAD := TRUE
BAD != I
```